# Finding Max Value From Text File

Tags: java, arrays, file, search, logic

I've been working to improve my java skills but still having trouble with some stuff. For this one program, everything seems to be functioning properly except my final output. Essentially, once it reads in numbers.txt, it is supposed to put the values into an array and then print out the largest number. There must be a flaw in my logic however, as currently it is only outputting the top number in the list rather than finding the largest number. Here is my program and I put a comment where I think my logic is flawed.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ProcessDataFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String fileName = "numbers.txt";
        String temp;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int i = 0;
        int[] numbers = new int[100000];

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (temp.isEmpty())
                    break;
                numbers[i++] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            }
        }
        // I think my logic error is somewhere in this section. 
        for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            if (max < numbers[i])
                max = numbers[i];



        System.out.println("The largest number is: " + max);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int max = integer[0];` whats `integer`

Comment: Might help to show us some content from `numbers.txt`.

Comment: perhaps you want to delete the question then. Or answer it yourself at worst. As it stands this is not a useful question.

Comment: It's literally just a text file of 10,000 numbers with one number per line. Currently it's listing the first number in the file rather than searching through the entire file.

Comment: can you share the file you are using to populate the array !!!

Comment: did you actually check that there's a number larger than the first number in the file ?

Comment: Sure, here's the first few numbers in the file. In the file, each number is on a new line. This goes on for 10,000 numbers. You can see already that 629685 is larger but it still keeps saying that 288991 is the largest. 

288991
217863
132563
201070
107775
108799
321178
599005
629685
574855
127988

Comment: Having run this locally, it seems to work.  This may be an issue with the numbers.txt file.  It may be to do with the line endings and temp.isEmpty() is being triggered and ending the loop early

Answer (score 1):

Yes, theres an error but not in your logic, yore missing `for` brackets, so just first line after `for` is inside the iteration. Look your code with correct identation

```
// I think my logic error is somewhere in this section. 
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    if (max < numbers[i])

max = numbers[i]; // this line is out of the for scope!!!
```

Just add the `{` and `}` to define loop scope

```
// I think my logic error is somewhere in this section. 
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    if (max < numbers[i])
        max = numbers[i];
}
```

Comment: Adding braces (curly brackets) to everything is a habit you should form.  It will save you from this pain time and time again.  I will kick the ass of any junior who does not put them in.  Therefore, you should add them to the if as well.

Comment: Totally agree @Xetius

Comment: I added the brackets but it still doesn't seem to be finding the largest number. Still giving the same number as it was before, the first one in the list.

Comment: I agree that it should be a habit, it still doesn't matter for this case as `for` loop is followed by `if` condition. Check [here](https://ideone.com/D4pJwc)

Comment: Before was the last... If now it is the first, then first must be the larger

Comment: how will curly braces effect this particular scenario ??? nothing seems to be out of scope here

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your numbers.txt file.  Will depend what platform you are on and what line ending it is expecting, but I believe that the code works.

Im running this code on a Mac, In IntelliJ with a txt file containing random numbers. It must be triggering the temp.isEmpty() condition and exiting after it has read the first item.

Check the file, particularly the line endings.

Also, if you can't step through the code in debug mode, try adding some System.out.println statements to clarify what is happening.

This code works for me.

Comment: What would be different? In my file every number is separated by line and there is no additional whitespace.

Comment: As I mentioned above, try either stepping through, to see what values you are getting, or add in some logging using System.out and you should be able to quite easily locate the issue.